# How to you properly create a slice in Golang using the reflect package?

Tags: go, reflection

I have a function that takes a struct type and attempts to pass in a `reflect.Type` and later get the address of a slice created with the `reflect` package but I can't seem to get the right type for the final object.

The hardcoded version looks like this:

```
val := new(StructA)
valSlice := make([]*StructA, desiredSize)
foo(&valSlice)
```

and the `reflect` version I have looks like this:

```
inputType := reflect.TypeOf(&StructA{}) // This is a requirement
structType := inputType.Elem() 
val := reflect.New(structType).Interface()

sliceType := reflect.SliceOf(inputType)
structSlice := reflect.MakeSlice(sliceType, desiredSize, desiredSize)
valSlice := structSlice.Interface()
```

This appears to work until I attempted to take the address of the two values:

```
foo(&val)
```

The hardcoded gives me this `&[<nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil>]` with type `*[]*main.StructA` and the generated gives me this `0xc00010a190` with type `*interface {}`.

Here is a repro of the issue with print statements littering for inspection: https://play.golang.org/p/ItKWS-PndTE

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `generatedSlice` is an `interface{}`, so you're taking the address of that interface value. What exactly do you want to so with that?

Comment: I'm trying use the Read function in `xitongsys/parquet-go`. https://github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go/blob/master/example/local_flat.go#L81

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/rieGXrhMBjA ?

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much @mkopriva. I understand what you did but I don't fully understand why what I did didn't work.

Comment: Taking the address of an `interface{}` does not take the address of the value referenced by the `interface{}`.

Comment: I see, thank you! Answer the question and I'll mark it as the answer